# Translate unicode emojis to ascii emojis in Python

Tags: python, unicode, nlp, emoji, emoticons

Is there a way to translate unicode emojis to an appropriate ascii emoticon in Python? I know the [emoji library](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/)  which can be used to convert unicode emojis to something like :crying_face:. But what I would need is to convert it to :'(

Is there an elegant way to do this without having to translate every possible emoji manually? Another option would be to convert the ascii emojis also to their textual representation, i.e. :'( should become :crying_face:.

My intermediate goal is to find a way to transform ascii and unicode emojis to a common representation. My final goal would be to replace emoticons (no matter if unicode or ascii) by the emotion they represent (if they do not represent an emotion, remove them)

Comment: Wouldn't the ASCII representation be pretty... opinion based? What would  become? I fear you'll have to define a translation table (i.e. a `dict`) yourself. You can get the name with `unicodedata.name('')`.

Comment: For my use case, it would be sufficient to only convert emoticons that transport an emotion and to drop all others. unicodedata.name is a good starting point. Maybe I can search the description this gives me for some keywords that indicate an emotion (like 'smiling' or 'sad')

Comment: just found out that `unicodedata.name(emoji_char)` basically returns the same as `emoji.demojize(emoji_char)` just that the format is different. unicodedata returns CAPITAL LETTERS WITHOUT UNDERSCORES and emoji returns :small_letters_with_underscores: but the text is basically the same.

Answer (score 5):

I found these repos that have a huge database of emoji's along with a `text` attribute(what you need):

https://github.com/alexmick/emoji-data-python

https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data (This is the original. The python one seems to be a wrapper on this)

You can find out more by exploring the examples in the repos. From the 
For the python version you can use the official unicode name/hex code to get the `EmojiChar` object:

```
In [31]: grin = emoji_data_python.find_by_name("GRINNING FACE")

In [32]: grin
Out[32]:
[EmojiChar("GRINNING FACE"),
 EmojiChar("GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES"),
 EmojiChar("GRINNING FACE WITH STAR EYES"),
 EmojiChar("GRINNING FACE WITH ONE LARGE AND ONE SMALL EYE")]

In [33]: grin[0].text
Out[33]: ':D'
```

Comment: But how to get from the text representation to the actual emotion? Is there something like a dictionary?

Comment: Install it, read the documentation and play around with it. Also I've added an example